# Stop Audio Playback on Action Exit

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

So my app contains endless playback from one intent. I want that when I exit the intent, the playback should stop. Currently when I exit the app closes but the audio keeps on playing. I have tried to patch it with a small jingle sound, but it throw an error this way. Is there a way to stop music before existing?

```
Typical conversation looks like following:
Person: Hey google, talk to my test app
Google: Hey welcome to audio station (plays audio).
Person: Hey google, stop the app.
Google: App exits (echo sound) (Audio keeps on playing).
```

This code is when google plays music

```
conv.ask(new MediaObject({
    name: track.name,
    url: track.URL, // This is a URL from our server, playing music
    description: track.description,
    icon: new Image({
        url: track.pic ? track.pic : defaultImageURL,
        alt: 'Media icon'
    });
```

And following code is for exiting the action:

```
conv.close('Bye bye');
```

Comment: Can you update your question to illustrate how you are doing "endless playback"? Possibly show the code that is generating this reply? It is difficult to help if we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Prisoner I updated the question. Dose that make sense now ?

Comment: A little. But it isn't clear how this is "endless". Or what you mean by "exit the Intent". What is the conversation supposed to look like, and what is actually happening?

Comment: @Prisoner Hey sorry for late response. By exit intent I mean closing the intent. I am attaching the sample conversation

Comment: Hey, it's just your question if you want it answered. {: What platform is this happening on? Smart speakers? Smart displays? Mobile?

Comment: Google home mini

Answer (score -1):

```
while waiting for response can sleep


while (!response.isDone()) {
  System.out.println("Waiting for response...");
  Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

or get end time

```
    System.out.printf(
        "\t%s.%s sec - %s.%s sec\n",
        wordInfo.getStartTime().getSeconds(),
        wordInfo.getStartTime().getNanos() / 100000000,
        wordInfo.getEndTime().getSeconds(),
        wordInfo.getEndTime().getNanos() / 100000000);
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like an answer to a different question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: hello you can set the audio playback to sleep! is relevant, just trying to help

Comment: Helping is always appreciated! But the question doesn't talk about setting a timer, it talks about a specific feature in AoG that appears to be doing audio playback incorrectly. See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: i figured a work around would be to make it sleep on exit so it stops playback immediately

Comment: Suggesting workarounds or other possible approaches is great! But you should be clear that is what you're offering, as well as discuss why you think it might work or how to implement it. As it says in the help I linked to: "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar action (and issue) I found "Goodbye" will exit the action and kill the stream. (but all my other utterances will not, I don't know why) Maybe if you use, ok google, goodbye. you will get a more favorable result.

Maybe reading below will help

Have an action which is playing a stream. When I say "Ok, Google Goodbye", the device exits the conversation & also stops the audio stream - Great!

However, If I use any of my alternate utterances ( cancel, i'm done, stop, quit,) etc. I get "Sorry,  isn't responding right now....". OR the device exits the conversation AND leaves the stream playing!! (not good!) In my research elsewhere, this is a known issue, but not one for which i see a resolution.

I want all "exit" utterances to have the same behavior as " Ok, Google Goodbye"

Is the "Sorry,  isn't responding right now...." an indication of incorrect handling of the utterances and or intents?

How do i debug this? One utterance works, the rest do not. Suggestions please?

Thanks

Steve

ps: I am beginning to understand why Google assistant is not as popular as "the A girl" IMO and experience, I am much more frustrated by the google company's lack of .... well lots of things on this platform (comparatively).

Google assistant actions seem to be geared much more around "conversation" (ie using words like talk to and goodbye) are conversational, which is ok, however, being forced to use "talk to" and "goodbye" IMO shows a lack of flexibility and vision, and is not appropriate for - all - actions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Comment: edited to suggest a course of action.

Comment: Please don't add *Me too* as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you are interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: This place seems over-the-top unnecessarily hostile